# What is the problem in my equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, projectile

Consider the following hypothetical scenario-

We are standing on the ground and throwing an object in the sky, whose initial velocity $\vec{v}$ makes an angle of 60 degrees with the horizontal, i.e, the ground. One of the crucial aspects of this scenario is that instead of being just subjected to the downward acceleration of gravity, the object is also facing constant leftward horizontal deceleration having magnitude equal to that of gravity.

I have tried to make a graph of the projectile motion in this scenario using desmos. But the shape of the graph is not matching with the shape I was expecting.

[image]

[image]

The scenario has been drawn on the left while the expected results have been drawn on the right.
Also, the second picture shows the final equation that I got of 'y' w.r.t 'x'. I put this equation in desmos.

[image]

But this is how the graph looked.

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Could you explain a bit what your model is which requires you to treat gravity as a horizontal force? Please bear in mind that help with individual calculations and "check my work" questions are off-topic, but the underlying principal might be on-topic.

Comment: @Jiminy Cricket it was just a hypothetical scenario given to us. We were supposed to draw the rough graph

Comment: In your first graph, you "expected result" shows a launch angle that is more like $80^\circ$ than $60^\circ$.

Comment: @hdhondt Shouldn't it be kind of similar considering the fact that in both cases the horizontal component is smaller than the vertical component and will thus become 0 before the vertical component

Comment: You have not given us any speeds. All you've told us is $g$ and the angle, $60^\circ$

Comment: @hdhondt why would the speeds matter?